# regex: match multiple allowed lengths?

Tags: regex

So I want to allow A-Z with a length of 8 or 12.

I tried:

```
^[a-z]{8|12}$
```

but that doesn't work. What's the correct solution? (without repeating)

Comment: Not possible without repeating.

Comment: `^[a-z]{8}(?:[a-z]{4})?$`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative to the "exactly 8 or exactly 12" types of patterns, here's an "8 and maybe 4 more" type pattern:

```
^[a-z]{8}([a-z]{4})?$
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to use alternation like this:

```
^([a-z]{8}|[a-z]{12})$
```

There is no other regex solution that would not involve repeating the `[a-z]` part. At least you do not have to repeat the `^` and `$` anchors if you use a grouping construct.

Alternatively, you may use an optional group, but that is only good when your pattern is static. Actually, the difference is negligent (tested at [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester)):

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I'd suggest this solution:

```
^([a-z]{4}){2,3}$
```

It means that the group [a-z] of length 4 has to match either 2 (total length: 8) or 3 (total length: 12) times. This way the set of allowed characters has to be defined only once.

Comment: While the answer works, i like the flexibility of this option.

Comment: The bounds specification with a comma is a range so changing to `{2,4}` would match 8, 12 or 16 rather than just 8 or 16 (which might be the case if it was a list instead of a range).

Comment: Yes, correct. To match a total length of 8 or 16 the expression can be adjusted to `^([a-z]{8}){1,2}$`. But this approach has its limits. It's only useful for sequencial lengths of multiples in a given or open range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^[a-z]{8}$|^[a-z]{12}$
```

The multiple length field option isn't there, you have to give them out separately including the regex